how to regenerate QuickFIX/j sources from my custom DataDictionary?
How do I regenerate the message/field sources based on my custom FIX50sp2 data dictionary?
I used to know how to do it back in the ant days, but it seems a lot has changed.  I have so far been unable to find any documentation that tells me what command or task to actually run.
The readme says to use mvnw clean install, but I'm not seeing my custom fields/messages in the generated sources after I run it.
Here's what I've done to set it up.

I added my custom DD xml file to quickfixj-messages/quickfixj-messages-fix50sp2/src/main/resources
I updated quickfixj-messages/quickfixj-messages-fix50sp2/pom.xml to only <include> my custom DD, and <exclude> the other two DDs.

What do I need to do to actually run the generator?

Ok, I got past it, but the whole deal seems kind of messy.
First off, I was running the maven command wrong; I was including the minimal-fix-latest param, which causes it to NOT generate my code.
The correct command is:
$ mvnw clean package -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -PskipBundlePlugin
Plus, I had to:

update quickfixj-messages/quickfixj-messages-all/pom.xml for this new DD

And then I was closer, but had build errors because some of the test code used classes that my DD wasn't creating anymore.  Even though I'm not running the tests, I needed them to build clean so that Maven would proceed through their steps.  So finally I had to comment out some code from (1) some unit tests and (2) ATMessageCracker.
This whole task seems like it should be easier.
